# How to wait for input element enabled in selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I am writing script to select and enter value in below screen in JIRA.

[image]
The 'issue type' is an 'input' element with autocomplete property:

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="issuetype-field" aria-controls="issuetype-suggestions">
```

Right after entering value for 'input type', the rest of fields such as 'summary' grey out for a few seconds. If I try to enter value for 'summary' field right after, using following code:

```
myDriver.findElement(By.id("summary")).sendKeys(summary);
```

summary field will not be entered, rather an error "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up.." will happen.

HTML code for 'summary' field is:

```html
<input type="text" value="" name="summary" id="summary" class="text long-field">
```

So **what i want is just to wait for 'summary' input field to be enabled** and then sendkey to it. I am looking for something like

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated
```

but instead i want '**enabled**', not `presenceOfElementLocated` or `visibilityOfElementLocated`. I do not want to use `Thread.sleep()` either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)`?

`elementToBeClickable` checks if the element is enabled.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: Cool. I knew this API but thought it only check 'clickable', did not read API doc in detail.

Comment: does not work for me - page is still loading after elementToBeClickable

Answer (score 7):

```
public void waitForElementEnabled(final WebElement element) {
    try {
        getWait().until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) driver -> element.isEnabled());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info(
                e + " : " + "Timed out waiting for element: " + element);
    }
}
```

The wait is a WebDriverWait and we want to wait until we get a true response when the WebElement is enabled. The driver is my WebDriver instance which is declared globally. If it timesout without getting a true response then I cantch the exception (so that the test will continue) and show a message informing that the operation timed out.
I'm using a Lambda expression so you need to be on selenium 3.1 or higher (with guava 21)

Comment: Please provide some explanation for the code provided in your answer