# Click and disabled element only once previous operation is complete

Tags: java, selenium

using Eclipse automating my application using Selenium. In my application there is a page were some data loads so applied an explicit wait until he data loads, now once that is loaded I save and that save time depends each time on the amount of data loaded. There is an element over the screen that becomes disabled during this Save operation and enabled only when Save operation is over. But her when I'm applying the explicit wait with Isclickable method it is not working. It reaches to that element before the save was over and tries clicking an disabled object. Can someone please help with this.

Comment: Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Comment: Hi PFB the piece of code tried:                                                                         Wait<WebDriver> wait1 = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver); 
                                                                                                                                                                                               WebElement ExpWait1= wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='show(views.overview)']")));
       ExpWait1.click();

Comment: I answered a similar question to this before, check my answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971546/how-to-wait-for-input-element-enabled-in-selenium-webdriver/44050066?noredirect=1#comment75126336_44050066

Answer (score 0):

Use implicit wait.
Or,
When element is enabled at that time only click the element.You need to check whether element is enabled or disabled.So for that try using Boolean.

Comment: tried implicit wait.. doesn't work out. Tried loop giving condition if with Isenabled true then click.. that also didn't work out.